# how to handle change in checkbox in ACtion Scripit FLEX?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, flex4.5

```
        protected function inital():void
        {
            var _cb:CheckBox;
            var _formitem:FormItem;
            for( var i:int =0;i<program.list.length;i++)
            {
                _formitem = new FormItem();
                _formitem.label = employee.list[i].INCLUDE_TYPE
                _cb = new CheckBox();
                _cb.styleName="gridCheckBox";
                _cb.selected = (employee.list[i].INCLUDE_IND == 'Y'?true:false);
                _formitem.addElement(_cb);
                Dynamic_Check.addElement(_formitem);

        }
```

i am using this code to generate checkbox on a panel this check box label and selected or nt coming from database.and its working fine .i want also if user change the check box while deselect the selecting one or select the delsecting one .so how should i apply change handler in Action scripit.Dynamic check is a form id.Employeee is a array collection which is retrieving value from java side .

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event lister to the check box. It will listen for change event:

```
_cb.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, handler);

 protected function handler(event:Event)
{
  //Here stays the code to be executed when a change ocurre 
}
```